# Basic JavaScript Array & For Loop Question

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm a beginner at JavaScript and I need help solving a problem. The assignment is:

**
/*
Arrays & Loops
Step 1
Create an empty array and assign it to a variable called "numberList".
*/

/*
Step 2
Using a for loop, place the numbers from 0 to 5 into the "numberList" array.
console.log the numberList array.
*/

/*
Step 3
Remove the last number in the array and console.log the array.
*/**

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var numberList = [];
for (let numberList = 0; numberList = 5; numberList++) {
    console.log(numberList);
};

var number = numberList.pop()
console.log(number);
```

When I run this in VSCode, it doesn't perform what the assignment is asking for. I've tried a lot of different options over and over again and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm expecting the sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to appear in an array, and then for the pop function to remove 5 from the array, but no matter what I do it's not working.

Comment: It should be `numberList < 5`; you want to loop while it's less than `5`.

Comment: @vr. OP expects the array to be like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` therefore the condition will be `numberList <= 5`

Answer (score 2):

The push() method is missing.

So please follow the below steps:

```
let arr = []; // Assigned the empty array to 'arr' variable.

for(let i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    arr.push(i); // Just push the looping values to 'arr' variable. 
}

console.log(arr) // Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.pop() // Removed the last index value 

console.log(arr) // Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right!

I recommend you to check how for loops work and what the index `i` in the code I provide you below does.

Also you might need to check how to place values into an array.

In JavaScript and in most languages we do

```js
array[position] = desiredValue;
```

And then to access the desired value we just need to do `array[position]`.

Feel free to ask any other question! We are here to learn.

```
** /* Arrays & Loops Step 1 Create an empty array and assign it to a variable called "numberList". */

const numberList = [];

/* Step 2 Using a for loop, place the numbers from 0 to 5 into the "numberList" array. console.log the numberList array. */

for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  numberList.push(i);
}

console.log(numberList);

/* Step 3 Remove the last number in the array and console.log the array. */
let number = numberList.pop();
console.log(numberList);
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Thank you for the grammar correction <3